# Reputation system from scratch. Limit number of current_user votes to 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

in [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) Ryan Bates showed how to implement reputation system from scratch. But is there any way to give the current_user only 1 vote, and check whether user has already voted for application, and if yes, restrict the possibility of voting?

I think something like this in **user.rb** should work, but I don't know ho to exactly write it

```
   def has_one_vote
      Restrict amount of user votes to 1
   end
```

Thanks

Comment: There's not really enough information here to go on.  What are the relationships between your models?

Comment: User has_many applications and application_votes. Application_votes belongs_to user and applications. Applications belongs_to user and has_many application_votes. Actually it is the same as in the cast, application instead of haiku Ryan used

Comment: here is this from-scratch solution https://github.com/railscasts/364-active-record-reputation-system/tree/master/youhaiku-from-scratch

Comment: Are you going to pass an argument to `has_one_vote` containing the Application instance you're checking for a vote?

Comment: I just want to check whether current_user has the ability to vote for application. If he does not exhausted the limit of votes (which is just 1) , than he can vote, otherwise he cannot

Comment: @IlyaCherevkov Please don't post this information in comments. Edit it into your question with the **edit** link below your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have Users, Votes, and Posts, and that users vote on posts.

You should add a uniqueness validator to the `Vote` class on the `user_id` attribute, scoped to the `post_id`. This limits the number of votes a user can have on a given post to one:

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  validates :user_id, uniquness: { scope: :post_id }
end
```

---

To limit the *total* number of votes a user can *ever* create, either remove the `scope` from the uniqueness validator, or (more correctly) move the foreign key into the `users` table.

That is, either this:

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  validates :user_id, uniquness: true
end
```

*or* this:

```
class User
  belongs_to :vote
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this restricts number of votes to 1 for one particular post, and I want to restrict it for all posts, e.g. If user voted for 1 post, he cannot give another vote for another post

Comment: Then remove the `scope`, and the user will only be able to ever create one Vote. See my updated answer.